# context.sync promise not resolving

Tags: office-js, word-addins

I'm trying to debug an issue with my Word Add-in. I'm attempting to get all the text from the body of the document. It works for some documents but not others and appears to be hanging on the first 'return context.sync()' operation and not getting to the '.then(function(){…}); Something in the formatting of the text is causing the issue but I don't know how to determine what. Document length does not appear to be a factor.

Can anyone give me a clue as to how to figure this out?

I've streamlined my code down to the following in an attempt to debug. While running in debug, I select-all, copy and paste from one doc and run this code in the console, I get the correct lenText value. But, for another doc, it only gets to the first "return context.sync()" and I never see the message "done context.sync()"

```
Word.run(function (context) {
  var doc = context.document;
  var originalRange = doc.body;
  originalRange.load("text");   
  console.log("try context.sync() " );
  return context.sync()
 .then(function () {
    log("done context.sync() " );
    var myText = originalRange.text;
    var lenText = myText.length;
    console.log("lenText: " + lenText);
  });
})
.catch(function (error) {
   console.log("Error: " + error);
   if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
   console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
   console.log("Something went wrong. Trying again");
   }
 });
```

I'm expecting to be able to get the full text of the document. But, if I can't for some reason, I'd like to be able to report that to the user and give the reason or find a way to work around the issue.

Thanks for your help (in advance!)

Comment: I can't quite understand your debugging procedure. Can you reproduce the problem in [Script Lab](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/wa104380862)? Also, if the content of the doc is what correlates with the problem, can you progressively remove parts of the content until you find what's causing the problem?

Comment: Hi Rick! I'm debugging by running in VS and running code (like above) in the console window. Actually, I have been progressively going through the content and found the first instance where the sync appears to hang and there doesn't appear to be anything significant about it. It's just another number/bulleted list. Of course, I haven't hacked into the doc's cab file to see what the actual difference is. I was hoping to avoid having to do that. But there have been plenty of other number/bulleted lists, tables, charts, etc. in the previous sections of the document. (Haven't tried script lab yet)

Comment: using Script Lab, context.sync() hangs in a different place- another table. But that also is after tables and lists in previous sections.

Comment: If you move that table to the beginning of the document, does it still hang on that table?

Comment: It's a numbered list (not sure if that makes a difference) and, yes, it does. More interesting- If I copy just that numbered list chunk to a new doc and run the same code in Script Lab on that document, it runs successfully. Could it be a timeout issue with context.load? could it be a text length limit I don't know about? I've repeatedly trimmed strings from the doc and the tipping point appears to be lenText: 62303 characters. If I add one more character it breaks.

Comment: I think this might be a bug. I suggest that you raise this issue on the [office-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose) repo.

Comment: Will do. It's odd. I just tried with yet another document and is cutoff at 64,052 characters. But this doc had a lot fewer customized tab stops and formatting.

Comment: It was definitely a bug in the office build. https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/697